# Docker can't connect to redis from another service

Tags: node.js, docker, redis

I can't figure out how to connect to my `redis` service from my `app` service. Using DDocker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40ocker for Mac.

I've tried connecting the various ways I've found on similar questions:

```
const client = redis.createClient({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379});

const client = redis.createClient({ host: 'redis', port: 6379});

const client = redis.createClient('redis://redis:6379');

const client = redis.createClient('redis', 6379); // and reversed args
```

I always get some form of:

> Error: Redis connection to localhost:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
>
> Error: Redis connection to redis:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.2:6379

**Docker containers**

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
0fd798d58561        app_app         "pm2-runtime start e…"   2 seconds ago        Up 7 seconds                                 app
65d148e498f7        app_redis       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up 8 seconds        0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp   redis
```

**Redis works:**

```
$ docker exec -it redis /bin/bash
root@65d148e498f7:/data# redis-cli ping
PONG
```

**Redis Dockerfile** (pretty simple)

```
FROM redis:4.0.9
COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
CMD ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
```

**app Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10.3.0-slim
RUN mkdir -p /app
COPY src/* /app/
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "start", "/app/ecosystem.config.js"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  redis:
    build: ./redis/
    container_name: redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    expose:
      - "6379"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      - 'API_PORT=6379'
      - 'NODE_ENV=production'
  app:
    depends_on:
      - redis
    build: ./app/
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /app/node_modules
    environment:
      - 'NODE_ENV=production'
```

Comment: Check your host 6379 port. Is anythings used that port ? `sudo lsof -i tcp:6379`

Comment: @TruongDang it shows no output. I originally used a different port but switched back to `6379` to debug. Both had the same error as noted above.

Comment: Can you build your image and  try replace `build: ./redis/` to `image: your_image_name_build_from_dockerfile` ?

Comment: Seem your `Redis` not yet start... May you need to check your docker file, and redis configuration...

Comment: @d-_-b can you verify that `docker ps` lists the redis container?

Comment: can you share the redis config file?

Comment: In his case, there is nothing run on `6379` port, that mean there is some problem with his Redis. It can be start and map to host port 6739

Comment: So the error message is `Redis connection to redis:6379 failed`? Which ip address does it show? Is it the same as `docker inspect redis` shows?

Comment: @gesellix yes both show the same IP `172.20.0.2:6379`

Comment: Please include the error message that doesn't show it connecting to localhost or 127.0.0.1 since that won't work between containers.

Comment: Try a `docker run --net container:app_app redis redis-cli -h redis ping`

Comment: @BMitch same error: `Could not connect to Redis at redis:6379: Connection refused`, when running `docker run --net container:app redis redis-cli -h redis ping`

Comment: And now what? `Could not connect to Redis at redis:6379: Name or service not known`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like your redis image is configured to listen on 127.0.0.1 rather than all interfaces. This is not an issue with the default redis images, so either use the official image from docker hub, or correct your configuration to listen on 0.0.0.0.

You'll be able to verify this with netshoot:

```
docker run --rm --net container:app_redis nicolaka/netshoot netstat -ltn
```

In the redis conf, listening on all interface is done by commenting out the "bind" line in redis.conf.

Comment: Thanks, binding to `0.0.0.0` worked! Isn't `FROM redis:4.0.9` a "default redis image"?

Comment: That's based off of an official image, but it appears that you've extended that image with your own configuration.

Comment: @BMitch Got this problem as well, although I'm not using `docker-compose.yml` and just a `docker run --name some-redis -p 6379:6379 -d redis` command instead. The output from `netstat`: https://i.imgur.com/Coq403Q.png

And I still can't connect to it via my `node` app

Comment: @Oscar without a docker-compose.yml, your containers are not being started on the same user created network, so you won't have DNS and container to container networking. That's a different question.

Answer (score 11):

Let me explain it in simple language. When you run `docker-compose up` it runs redis and app in separate containers. Now your app  needs to connect/access the redis container (remember redis is not at your machines localhost, its inside a container and runs inside it at default port `6379`). By default Docker will keep app container and redis container in same network and **you can access a container by its service name** (which in your case is redis and app) so in order to access redis from app container all you need is to use the default port `6379` and host will be the  service name (in your case "redis").

For a node application running in a container get access to Redis (which was also running in a container) by

```js
const redis = require("redis");
const client = redis.createClient(6379, "service-name-for-redis-container");
```

Answer (score 6):

I solve this problem changing the redis host from 'localhost' to 'redis', exemple:

`REDIS_HOST=redis`

`REDIS_PORT=6379`

After the change my docker service started to comunicate with redis.

Original forum answer: https://forums.docker.com/t/connecting-redis-from-my-network-in-docker-net-core-application/92405

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that I was binding a different port on redis:

```
redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
        - 49155:6379
```

And I was trying to connect to port 49155 but I needed to connect through port 6379 since the connection is from another service.

Comment: You saved my life.  My node app is from another service but I was trying to connect via 49155. But how can you know that? please tell me how? I was thought 49155 is a port that the reids container talking to  the whole world?

Answer (score 1):

both @Hadi Mir and @Anderson Contreira's answer  says the same thing and are correct as per my experience. upvote for that.

But i would like to give bit more clarity and detail for a beginner like me. If you are using docker compose and its in a network, other services can access the docker which is in a container using its container name.
one approach is using connection string like

```
redis://[[username][:password]@][host][:port][/db-number]
```

so, if we are to give container name and lets assume port is 6379 its gonna be like

```
redis://yourUsername:yourPassword@yourRedisContainerName:6379
```

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` from the `app` container's perspective won't be able to leave the `app` container. So the best bet is to use `redis` or the host's ip address.

If you want to reach `redis` from the `app` container, you'll need to link them or put them into the same network. Please add a `network` property to both services, using the same network name. Docker will then provide you with with valid dns lookups for the service names.

See the official docs at https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks (for the `service:` property) and https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network-configuration-reference (for the top-level `networks` property).

Comment: That not a problem, i usually use redis in my docker-compose. And it work like normal...

Comment: @TruongDang you're right - the relevant docs are https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: Then I'll follow your argument to check whether the Redis process has actually started

Comment: @gesellix thanks I've added a network and still same error. Redis does start up, which I can see in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the docker log. I found this error in my own Redis docker log:

```
2023-06-15 04:44:14 1:M 14 Jun 2023 21:44:14.768 # Possible SECURITY ATTACK detected. It looks like somebody is sending POST or Host: commands to Redis. This is likely due to an attacker attempting to use Cross Protocol Scripting to compromise your Redis instance. Connection aborted.
```